# System.Data.SQLite mapping (INTEGER, long)

Tags: sqlite, model-view-controller, system.data.sqlite

I'm using System.Data.SQLite to use EF6 with SQLite in an MVC project. We changed from SQL Compact Edition to SQLite. In the MVC models almost all of the IDs are stored as integers but when I use INTEGER PRIMARY KEY statement in SQLite (to make a field "autoincrement") System.Data.SQLite maps integer to long.

Is there any way to force the SQLite provider to map INTEGER into int instead of long?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"INTEGER PRIMARY KEY" is an alias for rowid, which is always a 64 bit integer, so no. https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html